# inding all possible non-repeating numbers with given digits

Tags: combinatorics

How to find all non-repeating number from the following digits:$0,2,4,5,7,8$
This is how I tried to solve it:
Since numbers can't start with 0, and the order of the elements matters, it has to be variation from 6th class
$V^k_n = V^5_6=\frac{6!}{(6-5)!}=120$ However this seems to be wrong, since the answer in my textbook is 600. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 5 choices for the first digit (not 0), then 5 for the second, 4 for the third, etc. Hence $5\cdot5!=600$.

Comment: How many digits long must the number be?  Specifically six digits long?  Pick the first digit.  As you noted, it cannot be a zero, so you have five choices.  Pick the second digit.  It cannot be whatever you just picked but now *can* be a zero, so again five choices.  Pick each remaining digit in sequence... how many options for each step.  Multiplying them gives what?

Comment: Also, as an aside, you wrote $(5-6)!=(-1)!$ which is outside the domain of the factorial function

Comment: What does $V_n^k$ mean?  And is this the right answer to the question asked?  If $V_n^k = k!/(k - n)!$ then it is the number of ways to choose 5 non-repeating digits from 6 digits which gives you the five digit numbers allowing numbers beginning with 0 which is not the answer at all.

Comment: Well that's how variation is marked in my textbook

Comment: What does "variation" mean and why does it equal $k!/(k-n)!$ ?  Does this answer the question.  Why did you think the answer is $V_n^k$?

Comment: Well as far as I managed to understand in class(before 2 years), group of  k different elements(k-class) chosen between n given elements where order matters is called variation, it seemed logical to me that variation is the answer to the challenge.

Comment: @Planet_Earth Instead of trying to apply formulae, why not just work it out from first principles?

Comment: But it isn't.  That would be choosing the number of ways to pick 5 numbers (possibly 0 would be the first digit) from 6 different numbers.  i.e. your numbers are exactly 5 digits long.  That isn't what the question asked for.   Since you are asked for 6 digits numbers you want $V_6^6$ and since you can't the first digit be 0, you want to subtract $V_6^1$.  So the answer should be $V_6^6 - V_6^1$.  But you shouldn't do formulas by rote.  You should think things out as almagast's comment shows.

Comment: Yes, variation *is* the way to answer it but you have to think *how* to apply it.  You can't just throw numbers in without thinking what they represent and how they should be applied.  That the first number can't be 0  means you have 5 to choose from on the first choice, not that you have 5 to choose from for all.  And basic common sense should tell you you can't choose 6 items from 5 choices.  For $V_n_k; k \ge n$.  Otherwise you get 6!/(5 - 6)! = 6!/(-1)! which is ... undefined.

Comment: As an aside, Richard Stanley uses $n^{\underline{k}}$ to denote $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$ and $n^{\overline{k}}$ to denote $n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+k-1)$, what he calls "falling factorials" and "rising factorials."  A brief search also yields other notations for falling factorials such as $~_nP_k, (n)_k, P(n,k),\dots$.  Due to so many competing notations for the same thing, it may help to be in the habit to instead use $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ unless you expect your audience to know the specific notation you use.  I for one had never seen the $V$ notation before.

Comment: @JMoravitz, the think with the notation is stupid I mean in my country(Bulgaria) one of my teachers(she's teaching industrial electronics) wasn't familiar with the notation for inverse trig function $sin^-1$ she stated that $sin^-1 \alpha = \frac{1}{sin \alpha} $ and that half of my equations are wrong.